# Neural network from Scratch (debugging)

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network

I have been trying to create a basic neural network from scratch in Python. This is what I came up with.

## Activation functions and Derivatives

```
def sigmoid(Z):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-Z))

def relu(Z):
    return np.maximum(0, Z)

# derivatives
def d_relu(Z):
    return (Z > 0) * 1

def d_sigmoid(Z):
    return sigmoid(Z) * (1 - sigmoid(Z))
```

## Initialization of Parameters

```
def initialize_params(layer_dims):
    W, b = {}, {}
    L = len(layer_dims)
    
    for l in range(1, L):
        W[l] = np.random.randn(layer_dims[l], layer_dims[l - 1]) * 0.01
        b[l] = np.zeros((layer_dims[l], 1))
    
    return W, b
```

## Forward Propagation

```
def forward_prop(X, W, b, activation_func='relu'):
    Z = np.dot(W, X) + b
    
    if activation_func == 'relu':
        A = relu(Z)
    elif activation_func == 'sigmoid':
        A = sigmoid(Z)
    elif activation_func == 'tanh':
        A = tanh(Z)
        
    return Z, A
```

## Cost

```
def compute_cost(A_L, Y):
    m = Y.shape[1]
    cost = -np.sum(Y * np.log(A_L) + (1 - Y) * np.log(1 - A_L), axis=1, keepdims=True) / m
    
    return np.squeeze(cost)
```

## Backward Propagation

```
def backward_prop(dA, A_prev, Z, W, activation_func):
    if activation_func == 'relu':
        dZ = dA * d_relu(Z)
    elif activation_func == 'sigmoid':
        dZ = dA * d_sigmoid(Z)
    elif activation_func == 'tanh':
        dZ = dA * d_tanh(Z)
    
    m = A_prev.shape[1]
    
    dW = np.dot(dZ, A_prev.T) / m
    db = np.sum(dZ, axis=1, keepdims=True) / m
    
    dA_prev = np.dot(W.T, dZ)
    
    return dA_prev, dW, db
```

## Update Parameters

```
def update_params(W, b, dW, db, learning_rate):
    L = len(W)
    for l in range(1, L):
        W[l] -= learning_rate * dW[l]
        b[l] -= learning_rate * db[l]
        
    return W, b
```

## Neural Network Class

```
class LLayerNeuralNet:
    def __init__(self, layer_dims, activation_funcs):
        self.layer_dims = layer_dims
        self.activation_funcs = activation_funcs
        self.L = len(layer_dims)
        
        # initalize W and b
        self.W, self.b = initialize_params(layer_dims)
        
    def train(self, X, Y, num_iter=1000, learning_rate=0.01, print_costs=True):
        self.Z, self.A = {}, {}
        self.dZ, self.dA, self.dW, self.db = {}, {}, {}, {}
        self.costs = []
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.A[0] = X
        
        for i in range(1, num_iter+1):
            # forward propagation
            for l in range(1, self.L):
                self.Z[l], self.A[l] = forward_prop(self.A[l-1], self.W[l], self.b[l], self.activation_funcs[l])

            # compute cost
            if i % 100 == 0:
                cost = compute_cost(self.A[self.L-1], Y)
                self.costs.append(cost)
                if print_costs:
                    print('Cost after %d: %f' %(i, cost))

            # backward propagation
            self.dA[self.L-1] = - np.divide(Y, self.A[self.L-1]) + np.divide(1 - Y, 1 - self.A[self.L-1])
            
            for l in reversed(range(1, self.L)):
                self.dA[l-1], self.dW[l], self.db[l] = backward_prop(self.dA[l], self.A[l-1], self.Z[l], self.W[l], self.activation_funcs[l])
            
            # update parameters
            for l in range(1, self.L):
                self.W[l] -= learning_rate * self.dW[l]
                self.b[l] -= learning_rate * self.db[l]
    
    def predict(X_pred):
        A_pred = {}
        A_pred[0] = X_pred
        for i in range(num_iter):
            for l in range(1, self.L+1):
                _, A_pred[l] = forward_prop(A_pred[l-1], self.W[l], self.b[l], self.activation_funcs[l])
        
        return (A_pred[self.L] > 0.5) * 1.0
```

## Creating a model and training it

```
layer_dims = [12288, 20, 7, 5, 1]
funcs = {1:'relu', 2:'relu', 3:'relu', 4:'sigmoid'}
model = LLayerNeuralNet(layer_dims, funcs)
model.train(train_x, train_y, learning_rate=0.0075)
```

After running for 1000 epochs, the costs are:

Cost after 100: 0.678129

Cost after 200: 0.667676

Cost after 300: 0.660471

Cost after 400: 0.655489

Cost after 500: 0.652033

Cost after 600: 0.649628

Cost after 700: 0.647949

Cost after 800: 0.646774

Cost after 900: 0.645949

Cost after 1000: 0.645369

I think this is incorrect because the cost is not reducing by much.
Is there a way to test if my implementation is correct?

Comment: Also, how should one go about debugging something like this?

Comment: What was the usecase in the first place you were trying to solve? Can you elaborate on that? Maybe you can try it on that usecase.

Comment: I was not trying to solve any particular problem. I learnt about neural networks from deeplearning.ai coursera course. I was just trying to create my own neural network just to make sure that I understood the theory (the programming assignments weren’t that great). I took the data set from the last assignment (cat vs non-cat classifier)

Answer (score 1):

A good way to make sure your implementation is functional is by starting with a simpler problem, like testing your implementation with XOR. From the looks of it, the problem could be as simple as increasing the number of parameters in the network. Feeding values from 12288 input nodes into 20 hidden nodes is a drastic reduction and could cause a loss of information that your model needs to reduce the cost further.